# Resending a Model resets values in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

**This is my View:**

```
@model test2.Models.ChatModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Channel";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

}

<center>
    <h2>Channel: @Model.channelName</h2>

    @{
        foreach (string line in Model.chatLog) {
            <div>@line</div>
        }     
    }

    <br />

    @using (Html.BeginForm("sendMessage", "Home", FormMethod.Post)) {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.message)
        <button type="submit"> Send Message </button>
    }

</center>
```

**Here is my Controller:**

```
public ActionResult sendMessage(ChatModel model) {

            //send message somewhere

            //this is not working
            return RedirectToAction("Channel", "Home", new { channel = model.channelName });

            //this is working
            return RedirectToAction("Channel", "Home", new { channel = "test" });
}
```

The error happens in the redirectToAction method. Somehow "model.channelName" is empty, but @Model.channelName in my view is correctly displaying the channel name.

It looks like when you send a Model to a view, and "resend" this model back to a controller, the informations are lost.

Is there an easy way to solve this?

PS Step by step:

1. Model gets channelName
2. Model is send to view
3. View correctly displays data from model
4. adding message to Model
5. sending model to controller
6. model does NOT contain information from step 1

Comment: You are not generating a form control for `channelName`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include model.channelName in the form. Try adding a:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.channelName)
```

Anything not posted by the form, will be null in your model (including your chatlog)

Comment: simple solution. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Actually the values model properties should be rendered as input elements within the form that is posted back to controller action. The properties which are not included would loose their values.

What you can do is create a hidden field for those to post :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("sendMessage", "Home", FormMethod.Post)) {
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.message)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.channelName)
    <button type="submit"> Send Message </button>
}
```

You would need to add same way other properties too that are posting `null` at action and you need those for some processing.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Simple solution. Thank you